# How to run Spring RESTful project under tomcat 8?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, gradle, spring-boot, tomcat8

I am following next tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

I noticed that thay don't use tomcat to run their project. They use "gradle run" command to run it.
Is it possible to run that Spring project under tomcat?

Also, I want to know if it is resonable. Do we need tomcat to run spring RESTful projects (Maybe it is better to run with "gradle run" command)?

I am using Intellij IDEA and gradle 3.0

I have next build.gradle content:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.0.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-rest-service'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
}
```

All classes like in tutorial

Comment: Simply go step by step through the tutorial and run the project either from your IDE or from command line using mvn run:spring-boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the embedded Tomcat that Spring Boot provides, you can just use the `spring-boot-starter-web` starter and run the project with `spring-boot:run`.

But, as you set `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` as provided, I think you want to use an external Tomcat.

Here you can find the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) for WAR creation. You need to use the WAR gradle plugin, configure your Tomcat instance and run the project with `spring-boot:run` as usual.

> If you’re using Gradle, you need to modify build.gradle to apply the war plugin to the project:
>
> apply plugin: 'war'
>
> The final step in the process is to ensure that the embedded servlet container doesn’t interfere with the servlet container to which the war file will be deployed. To do so, you need to mark the embedded servlet container dependency as provided.
>
> dependencies {
>       // …
>       providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
>       // …
>   }

Answer (score 0):

RESTful Web Service as its name suggests is a service running on Web(HTTP protocol).And if you want to run any application on Web,you need to deploy it on WEB SERVER.Tomcat is a web server.Yes,you need Tomcat((or JBoss,Websphere,Weblogic,...server)) to run Spring or any RESTful web service.Gradle is dependency management tool,it can help you with building the required executables(like .war in case of Web Services/applications).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to run Spring Boot projects using the Spring Boot Run Configuration in Idea.

Just create a new run configuration and specify the `Application` as the main class. More info at official [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/run-debug-configuration-spring-boot.html).

However, you may run it in the Tomcat as well. That means creating a Tomcat Run Configuration and deploying a resulting war there, however that's much more cumbersome.